# Create button that inserts typed value from adjacent input into URL?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, button, input

I have a form that contains multiple inputs, and each input has its own respective button. I'm looking to have each button insert the adjacent input's typed value into a new browser tab and opens that address on click of the button.

Let’s say I type 121680573 into the text field, and when I click the button next to the field, this address should be opened in a new tab:

> a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/JobsQueryByNumberServlet?passjobnumber=**121680573**&passdocnumber=&go10=+GO+&requestid=0

The typed value would have to be inserted into that specific position after the = sign.

Thus far this is the only code I've come up with to accomplish this task (I created an alert for the sake of this example being I don't know how to accomplish the insertion of text). #bis represents the button:

```
$(document).ready() {
    var bis_button = $('.bis_button');
        bis_button.click(function() {
            alert(bis_button.val());
        });
});
```

The inputs and buttons are arranged like this in a WordPress page. Each input is assigned an ID by the WordPress plugin that's creating the page:

```
<div id="frm_field_[id]_container" class="frm_form_field form-field [required_class][error_class]">
    <label  class="frm_primary_label">[field_name]
        <span class="frm_required">[required_label]</span>
    </label>
    [input]
    [if description]<div class="frm_description">[description]</div>[/if description]
    [if error]<div class="frm_error">[error]</div>[/if error]
<div class="bis_button">View in BIS</div>
</div>
```

I've attached an image that shows the fields and their respective buttons.:

[image: Buttons & Fields]

Comment: `window.open('?passjobnumber=' + this.value);`?

Comment: Please, provide the HTML code to the question

Comment: @Hast: Was adding it just as you replied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".bis_button").click(function() {
        var inputValue = $(this).parent('.frm_form_field').find('input').val();

        window.open('a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/JobsQueryByNumberServlet?passjobnumber='+inputValue+'&passdocnumber=&go10=+GO+&requestid=0');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
bis.click(function() {
    var prefix = "a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/JobsQueryByNumberServlet?passjobnumber=";
    var suffix = "&passdocnumber=&go10=+GO+&requestid=0"
    var url = prefix + $(this).siblings("input[type='text']").val() + suffix;

    window.open(url,'_blank');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer tyme, I went with Hast's answer for the jQuery.